# How to identify an element in Selenium WebDriver that does not have any unique identifier/property?

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There are two buttons on application named as "download" & "upload" with same properties/identifiers. Can someone help me how to click on button & how to handle such objects. I have tried CSS Selector, XPath other combinations as well, nothing worked for me. looking for Java code.
below is the HTML for those buttons:

```
<div class="control-label col-md-6 control-label-left"> <button class="btn blue form-control-btn" ngf-select="vm.uploadDemographic($file)"> <i class="fa fa-upload"/> Upload Template </button> </div> 2nd Button <div class="control-label col-md-6 control-label-left"> <button class="btn blue form-control-btn" ng-click="vm.downloadTemplate('demographic')"> <i class="fa fa-download"/> Download Template </button> </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: The CSS for both the `WebElement` is identical so in absence of `id` or `name` attribute to construct an unique `css_selector` or an `xpath` we need to see some portion of the outerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following CSS Selector: `.btn.blue.form-control-btn`. It must help you.

Code:

```
buttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".btn.blue.form-control-btn"));
buttons.get(0).click(); // Click on the first button.
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i tried that before it's not working as both the buttons have same class. please check above html once. 1st & 2nd button HTML code & also unable to click by index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for finding your buttons:

**For download button**: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Download Template']"));`

**For upload button**: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Upload Template']"));`